# Why does try except not work in this case?

Tags: python, try-except

I have this piece of code here:

```
money_to_dep = int(input(f"\nHow much money do you want to deposit?(enter amount ONLY):\n>> "))
while True:
    try:
        print(money_to_dep)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Wrong INPUT. Try again.")
        break
```

When I type a string instead of an integer, an error still occurs even though I have done `except ValueError`? Why does this happen? This question really annoys me as I have never been able to have a clear understanding as to how try-except works with handling errors.

Comment: put the `int(input())` inside `try/except`

Comment: The statement `money_to_dep = int(input(f"` is not under `try:`. Also, why do you need `while True:`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh , i am working at a larger scale program and i just wanted to shorten it for you to understand

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your code like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        money_to_dep = int(input(f"\nHow much money do you want to deposit?(enter amount ONLY):\n>> "))
        print(money_to_dep)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Wrong INPUT. Try again.")
```

The ValueError raise when you use int. So it has to be inside the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your exception is occuring before your try catch. you need to put your input code inside try, so it can catch exception.

i.e

```py
money_to_dep = int(input(f"\nHow much money do you want to deposit?(enter amount ONLY):\n>> "))
```

Exveption occurs, but not in try block so not catched. Change it to

```py
while True:
    try:
        money_to_dep = int(input(f"\nHow much money do you want to deposit?(enter amount ONLY):\n>> "))
        print(money_to_dep)
        break
    except Exception as E:
        print(f"Wrong INPUT. Try again.")
        break
```

Comment: You have to remove break in the except. (try again it's said)